# Interpolating missing data

Tags: interpolation, data

I have a data set that contains data of the form (x0, y0, f1, f2, i1, i2, i3). The (x0, y0) are the coordinates, while the values f1 and f2 are real numbers (i1, i2, i3 correspond to some integers which are used as indices). The data can be downloaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/0xtxn8rggjorhdj/basins_%2528L4%2529.out/file).

Now I plot the (x0, y0) coordinates of the data with i2 = 4, where each point is colored according to the value of f1.

[image]

As you can see, there are missing points. The data set with all the missing points can be found [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/obqpo2pfq56sa24/data_LGs.dat/file)

[image]

Now, how can I use the original data with the f1 and f2 values, so as to interpolate and predict the f1 and f2 values of the missing points? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

read the data:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data = Import["basins_(L4).out.txt", "Table"];
```

interpolate $f_1$ and $f_2$: linear interpolation on irregular grid,

```
F1 = Interpolation[{{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, #[[3]]} & /@ 
       Select[data, #[[6]] == 4 &], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
F2 = Interpolation[{{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, #[[4]]} & /@ 
       Select[data, #[[6]] == 4 &], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

evaluate $f_1$ and $f_2$ on the entire grid (interpolate missing data):

```
T1 = Table[{x,y, F1[x,y]}, {x,Union[data[[All, 1]]]}, {y,Union[data[[All,2]]]}];
T2 = Table[{x,y, F2[x,y]}, {x,Union[data[[All, 1]]]}, {y,Union[data[[All,2]]]}];
```

plots of the interpolated functions in the style of [@kickert's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201176/26598):

```
ListPointPlot3D[Join @@ T1]
```

[image]

```
ListPointPlot3D[Join @@ T2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `Predict` function can provide you the information you need.

Start by importing your data into Mathematica.  For me, it was easiest to change the file extensions to `.txt` and use `SemanticImport`.

```
rawdata = SemanticImport["basins_(L4).txt"] // Normal;
missing = SemanticImport["data_LGs.txt"] // Normal;
```

Then pull out the subset that with i2=4.

```
subset = Select[rawdata, #[[6]] == 4 &]
```

You can now thread your (x0, y0) values to the f1 values:

```
f1aidata = Thread[subset[[All, 1 ;; 2]] -> subset[[All, 3]]]
```

At this point you have some choices to make around the Method and Performance Goals you use for the `Predict` function.  We could go deep in the weeds on this, but I created some training and test data and ran through all the options and found `GradientBoostedTrees` was the best compromise between quality and computational time.

```
f1predictor = 
 Predict[f1aidata, Method -> "GradientBoostedTrees", 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

With the Predictor you just created, you can run the missing data through it.

```
f1outputs = f1predictor[#] & /@ missing;
```

Then combine the inputs and outputs and `Join` the lists

```
f1missingresults = Append[Transpose[missing], f1outputs] // Transpose;
combinedresults = Join[subset[[All, 1 ;; 3]], f1missingresults];
```

Using a `ListDensityPlot`, you get this:

```
ListDensityPlot[combinedresults, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

Looking at the `ListPointPlot3D` you can see it isn't perfect, but it is very close.

```
ListPointPlot3D[combinedresults]
```

[image]

If you want to use this for f2, then follow the same process pulling your data from `subset[[All,{1,2,4}]]` and creating a new predictor

Comment: `GradientBoostedTrees` seems to get much worse results than a simple [linear interpolation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201170/26598): with the latter, you cannot see any residual structure in the `ListPointPlot3D` of the result.

Comment: I actually found that the `GaussianProcess` method was more accurate, but running the full data set through the `Predict` function was prohibitively time consuming.  The interpolation approach is much faster and cleaner.

Comment: I've been doing a lot of machine learning work recently... When you have a hammer in your hand, everything looks like a nail. ;-)

Comment: No worries, this is certainly a very interesting method for when the data are a bit less regular and ML can show its strengths better.

Comment: (+1) For imputing missing values with Decision Trees (DT's) -- DT's can be very good for imputation. (And, yes, there are better solutions for this case...)